# How to get a random document in pyes from elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pyes

How do I use pyes to get a random document?  I have a new cluster I have access to and want to explore

```
from pyes import *
conn = ES('127.0.0.1:9200', timeout=3.5)
#Now what?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance, you could match any document using `MatchAllQuery` and return a random one using `start=xxx` and `size=1`. Note that I've arbitrarily chosen `1000` to create a random number, but you can change this number to better match the number of documents you have in your index.

```
import random
from pyes import *
conn = ES('127.0.0.1:9200', timeout=3.5)

q = MatchAllQuery()
rnd = random.randint(1, 1000)     <-- 1000 depends on how many docs you have
docs = conn.search(Search(query=q, start=rnd, size=1))

random_doc = docs['hits']['hits'][0] <-- your random document
```